# How to listen for click events on the whole page in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

I'm experimenting with the leaderboards example and I would like to unset the `selected_player` when you click outside a player name. I figured for this to work, I'd need to add a listener event to the body element and prevent it from triggering other elements that are inside it. Then I would set `selected_player` to 0.

However I only seem to be able to add event maps to Templates?

```
  Template.player.events({
    'click': function () {
      Session.set("selected_player", this._id);
    }
  });
```

Am I missing something?
**How can I listen to a 'click' event for the whole page?**

Comment: put the body inside a template and a event to the template

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no good way to bind events to the whole body. However, you can wrap all your code in one outer template that has events, as Narven suggests.

```
<body>
  {{> outer}}
</body>

<template name="outer">
   your stuff
</template>
```

and

```
Template.outer.events({
  'click': function () {
    do stuff 
  }
});
```